# Java vector help

Tags: java, collections, vector

I have just started the Java. Please let me know what this statement says

```
class ABC{
transient Vector<int> temp[];

ABC(int max)
{
 this.temp = new Vector [max];
}
```

Is it creating a vector of int which size is max?

I am C++ person.

Comment: @Justin: Not even by a long shot. In fact if I'm not incorrect, this snippet looks like C++.

Comment: @Esko, ok, I didn't think so.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 4):

That creates an array of Vector objects. The length of the array is whatever is passed in as "max".

If you want a single Vector, leave off the []'s. A couple of changes are necessary to get the above code to compile.

```
import java.util.Vector;

class ABC
{
    transient Vector temp[];

    ABC(int max)
    {
        this.temp = new Vector[max];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness -- the Vectors in the array are of type "int", analagous to a C++ template.

Comment: @belwood. Java will scream if you pass an int to a Collection.

Answer (score 3):

No,

To create a Vector of initial capacity max you should

```
Vector<Integer> v = new Vector (max)
```

Note two things:

- Usage of Integer and not int. In Java, Integer is an object, while int is a primitive type. Collections can't use primitive types, they use objects.
- The capacity of the v is not limited to `max` elements. It will grow if you insert more than `max` Integers.

But let the [API page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(int)) do the talking

> The Vector class implements a growable
>   array of objects. Like an array, it
>   contains components that can be
>   accessed using an integer index.
>   However, the size of a Vector can grow
>   or shrink as needed to accommodate
>   adding and removing items after the
>   Vector has been created.
>
> ```
> Each vector tries to optimize storage management by maintaining a
> ```
>
> capacity and a capacityIncrement. The
>   capacity is always at least as large
>   as the vector size; it is usually
>   larger because as components are added
>   to the vector, the vector's storage
>   increases in chunks the size of
>   capacityIncrement. An application can
>   increase the capacity of a vector
>   before inserting a large number of
>   components; this reduces the amount of
>   incremental reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(int)) for the Vector constructor in question.  What you are most likely looking for is

```
this.temp = new Vector<int>(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

class ABC{
transient Vector<**Integer**> temp[];

ABC(int max)
{
 this.temp = new Vector [max];
}

read Integer instead of int. Yes it's working code.